# NFC freezing after format error

Tags: android, nfc, mifare, lg

After getting an NdefFormatable object, if tag is being pulled out of range, then NdefFormatable.format is being called, the function failure to return, causing the calling thread to "freeze".

To solve this, the unique solution found is restart the NFC resource of device. It's horrible for me, because need root privilegies.

This problem seems to happen only on some devices:

- Occurs on LG L90 (LG-D410hn) with Android 5.0.2 (tested in 3 devices different)
- Tested on Motorola Moto X 2013, and not happens.

My code:

```
ndefFormatable = NdefFormatable.get(tag);

if (ndefFormatable == null) {
    return;
}

formatted = false;

final Thread thread2format = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ndefFormatable.connect();
            ndefFormatable.format(ndefMessage);  // if communication interrupts, freeze this thread
            formatted = true;
            ndefFormatable.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};
thread2format.start();

try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (!formatted) {
    ndefFormatable.close(); // freeze too
}
```

Anyone have some ideas to fix this?

Comment: You should catch the TagLostException and retry the format() when the tag comes back into range.

Comment: But none exception is raised, just freeze. even tf I close app, the NFC is not working in all applications. Then I need to restart NFC (disable/enable manually).

Comment: What type of tag are you using?

Comment: I'm using only MifareClassic (1K)

Comment: I wonder what NFC chipset the LG phone is using? Broadcom or NXP. This link might shed some light on your issue. http://www.andytags.com/nfc-tags-compatibility-issues.html#.Vvqr8lUrJD8

Comment: Thank you you @jgriffin I don't know which chipset the LG D410 uses, but your link gave me hope. I will try another tag types.